# Android Retrofit json response into google map error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, retrofit

i'm using for firts time Retrofit on my Android app.
This is the structure of json object that i have to retrive:

```
{
"placemarks":[
  {
     "address":"Via di Santa Maria a Marignolle, 15, 50124 Firenze",
     "coordinates":[
        11.23348,
        43.75855,
        0
     ],
     "engineType":"CE",
     "exterior":"GOOD",
     "fuel":100,
     "interior":"GOOD",
     "name":"049/EV284TP",
     "smartPhoneRequired":false,
     "vin":"WME4513341K774636"
  }
 ]
}
```

i have write this Pojo model for object "placemarks" and all otehr items.
And i have write this code to retrive the json data and put it into map:

```
private void getPlacemark(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc=roma&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<ResponsePlacemarks> call = service.getPlacemark();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePlacemarks>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ResponsePlacemarks> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.d("response: ", String.valueOf(response.body()));
            try {
                mMap.clear();
                // This loop will go through all the results and add marker on each location.
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getPlacemarks().size(); i++) {
                    Double lat = response.body().getPlacemarks().get(i).getCoordinates().get(1);
                    Double lng = response.body().getPlacemarks().get(i).getCoordinates().get(0);
                    String placeName = response.body().getPlacemarks().get(i).getAddress();
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    // Position of Marker on Map
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    // Adding Title to the Marker
                    markerOptions.title(placeName);
                    // Adding Marker to the Camera.
                    Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    // Adding colour to the marker
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                    // move map camera
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });



}
```

but now when i run app the json are note load and i have error in the first line of for loop:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List android.mobility.com.mobiity.model.ResponsePlacemarks.getPlacemarks()' on a null object reference

Hi have found the error.
On APIService i have set @GET method in this way: @GET(".") because i use as URL the URL into BaseURL. So if i set all url into @GET the method works fine.
How i can use only the url into BaseULRalso into @GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can only call `response.body()` exactly once.

So, comment this.

```
// Log.d("response: ", String.valueOf(response.body()));
```

And extract that list variable

```
final ResponsePlacemarks _response = response.body();
final List<Placemark> placemarks = _response.getPlacemarks();

for (int i = 0; i < placemarks.size(); i++) {
    final Placemark p = placemarks.get(i);
    Coordinates c = p.getCoordinates();

    Double lat = c.get(1);
    Double lng = c.get(0);

    String placeName = p.getAddress();
```

And if that doesn't work, then you need for the Java object to exactly match the JSON response, otherwise it is null

> How i can use only the url into BaseULRalso into @GET?

Your base URL should look like something this

```
https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1
```

Then you should be able to have something like

```
@GET("/vehicles")
public ResponsePlacemarks getVehicles(
    @Query("oauth_consumer_key") String key, 
    @Query("format") String format
    @Query("loc") String loc
);

public ResponsePlacemarks getVehicles(String loc) {
    return getVehicles("roadzapp", "json", loc);
}
```

Or maybe just

```
@GET("/vehicles?format=json")
public ResponsePlacemarks getVehicles(
    @Query("oauth_consumer_key") String key, 
    @Query("loc") String loc
);
```

---

The reason for putting the key into the method call is that you shouldn't store the key as a string on your device for security reasons.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely your POJO does not match the JSON structure.
Can you post your POJO class and how are you deserializing the JSON?

Comment: You should post this in the comments above.

Comment: @cricket_007 Are you the stackoverflow police? As far as I'm concerned I answered the question with the most likely cause of the issue. Why don't you use the comments since the second part of your response is exactly what I answered (and again most likely the cause of the NPE)

Comment: Considering you asked a question in your answer, I'd say that doesn't make a good answer... My answer, on the other hand addresses the other problem of OkHttp only allowing `response.body()` to be called once.

Comment: So if I delete the question it would be an acceptable answer, right? I'm quite new to this so I'll keep that in mind for the future :)

Comment: I would say an acceptable one would include the correct Java object, or you could comment above and wait for the question to be updated

Comment: Thank you officer I'll take your advice :)